# C# SubmitChanges dont work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to make a database. I made a form and I want to get the data from that. Everything seems okay, but my database didn't get the update and didn't change. I'm using a local database. I tried to change "Copy to output directory" but nothing happened... The SubmitChanges seems ok: I get the Message, but after the program is closed the database doesn't contain the new data... I saw a lot of posts with similar problems, but I didn't find a solution.

My Code:

```
private void felvetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Match m = new Match();
        try
        {
            m.datum = f2.datumTextBox.Text;
            m.mod_fk = Convert.ToInt32(f2.modTextBox.Text);
            m.acc_fk = Convert.ToInt32(f2.accTextBox.Text);
            m.champion = f2.champTextBox.Text;
            m.szerep_fk = Convert.ToInt32(f2.roleTextBox.Text);
            m.kimenet = f2.resultTextBox.Text;
            m.mhossz = f2.lengthTextBox.Text;
            m.kill = Convert.ToInt32(f2.killTextBox.Text);
            m.death = Convert.ToInt32(f2.deathTextBox.Text);
            m.assist = Convert.ToInt32(f2.assistTextBox.Text);
            m.kda = float.Parse(f2.kdaTextBox.Text);
            m.killpart = float.Parse(f2.kpTextBox.Text);
            m.farm = Convert.ToInt32(f2.farmTextBox.Text);
            m.ward = Convert.ToInt32(f2.wardTextBox.Text);
            m.redward = Convert.ToInt32(f2.redwTextBox.Text);

            db.SubmitChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("New match added to the database!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't tell the db what changes you want to submit.  As far as its concerned, it has nothing to do with your `match` object -- same as the `f2` object.

Comment: What is `db` anyway? But like Amy says, you need to associate `m` with it.

Comment: You also don't need the nested try/catch blocks.  The outer block will catch any exception thrown by the SubmitChanges() call.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I removed that try/catch block, and added the "insertonsubmit" suggested below. I have another problem now, I'ts below...

Answer (score 4):

Don't you have to make the entity layer aware of this new object?  I imagine you need to call something like this for new entities:

```
db.Matches.InsertOnSubmit(match);
```

Its perfectly fine to load entities from the database via this entity layer, modify them, and then use `db.SubmitChanges()` because the entity layer already knows about existing objects!  How is it supposed to know about this new object if the entity layer doesn't have any reference to it?

Comment: Or `db.Matches.Add(match)` if you're using EF <= 6.

Comment: I did what you said, and I realized it was the missing link! But now I get an error, it says: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity columnin table 'Match' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF". In the program I have 'Service based Database' and 'Linq to sql classes'. I had a similar program earlier, with the same codes and "setup" but that works... I think it's something with the database(I think I'm missing something on that side...). Any idea?

Comment: It means your table in DB have autoincrement column, and you are trying to set value for this column manually. Exclude this column from inserting or set IsIdentity = false for table identity column